# How to solve the differential equation $(1-x^2)y''-2xy'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P_n(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

So I was reading back over my course problem sheet for differential equations ( I'm studying  for exams right now) and I came across this question:

Given that

$$\tfrac{2}{(5-4x)^{1/2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{1}{2^n}P_n(x)$$

For $|x|\leq1$

Find a particular solution of the equation

$$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'=\tfrac{2}{(5-4x)^{1/2}} -1$$

I've been wracking my brains trying to solve it but I can't figure out how.  From my research I found that one way to solve a second order linear inhomogenous differential equation ( as this one is ) is to use the method of variation of parameters. However my teacher assured me that this could be solved using only material covered in the notes and this method is not in them.

Here's what we covered  up to the point of the notes that corresponded to this question. He also said that we should be able to solve any question in the course without referring back to our first course in solving o.d.e.'s which thought us methods such as froebenius, characteristic equations, integrating factor method etc ....

```
  1) Linear independence of functions

     a) Criteria for checking linear independence

     b)Finding a second solution 


  2) Orthogonal function expansions (Sturm-Liouville theorem)


    a) Self adjoint form

    b) linear independence  

    c)Orthogonality 

    d)Completeness
```

So my question is how can we use the concepts I've listed to solve this equation , or is it even possible to do so ? Even though he said it was it seems like there's just a few ingredients missing!

Note:just to be clear this isn't a homework question it's just from a problem sheet i'm studying for my exam in a few weeks.

Comment: You can do it in an eigenfunction expansion by rewriting the homogenous ODE into Sturm-Liouville using an integration factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $P_n(x)$'s are the Legendre polynomials, which satisfy
$$ (1 - x^2)P_n''(x) - 2xP_n'(x) = -n(n+1)P_n(x).$$

Therefore, if $f(x)$ is the function
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n P_n(x),$$
then the solution to the differential equation
$$ (1 - x^2)y'' - 2xy' = f(x)$$
must be
$$ y=- \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n(n+1)}P_n(x).$$

Your question is a special case, with $a_n = 1 / 2^{n} - \delta_{n, 0}$.

Comment: So all you have to do is take the LHS of your first equation then say : $-n(n+1)y=\sum a_n P_n(x) \Rightarrow y= - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n(n+1)}P_n(x) $ ? That's a lot easier than I thought it was going to be ! Do you perhaps have any good links to literature regarding particular solutions to inhomogeneous versions of Legendre, Hermite, Laguerre etc .. It wasn't covered well in class at all and I'd like to do some extra study on it. By the way thank you so much for your post , I would have spent hours going down the wrong path had you not shown me how simple it was :)

Comment: @can'tcauchy Try plugging my solution into the equation, and verify that it satisfies the equation! You'll see that $$ \left[ (1 - x^2) \frac{d^2}{dx^2} - 2x \frac{d}{dx}\right] \left( - \frac{a_n }{n (n+1)} P_n (x)\right) = a_n P_n(x)$$ holds for each $n$.

Comment: @can'tcauchy Important and related revision exercise: Solve the equation for _arbitrary_ $f(x)$. Hint: use the orthogonality properties of the Legendre polynomials to show that $f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n P_n (x)$, where $a_n =  \frac{2n + 1}{ 2}  \int_{-1}^1f(x) P_n (x)$. (See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Orthonormality_and_Completeness) Then use the same technique...

Comment: thank you this all helps a lot :) By chance I don't suppose you know of any links or even books that have any worked examples of questions like this do you ? I usually learn the underlying concepts best by seeing them applied ?

Comment: @can'tcauchy Perhaps Riley Hobson and Bence?

Comment: Okay so I tried working through what you said and here is what I got : We have the Legendre equation $(1-x^2)y''-2y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tfrac{1}{2^n}P_n(x)$. but we know that the LHS has as its solutions the legendre polynomials with eigenvalue -n(n+1). we have a function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nP_n(x)$ then we can use orthogonality of the the legendre equations to find that $a_n=\tfrac{1}{2^n}$ but I still don't see how we can use orthogonality to deduce that the solution must be $y=- \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n(n+1)}P_n(x).$

Comment: what makes more sense to me though I don't think it's rigorous enough to use in an exam (maybe I'm wrong though) is that if the legendre equation of the form $(1-x^2)y''-2xy'=-n(n+1)y$ has the solution $P_n(x)$, then if on the rhs of this equation we have instead $\sum_{0}^{\infty}\a_nP_n(x)$ then this implies the solution must be $\sum_{0}^{\infty}\tfrac{- a_n}{n(n+1)}P_n(x)$ as it cancels the -n(n+1) in the original equation multiplies by $a_n$ and sums the result i.e. it makes the solution conform to the fact that this time the eigenvalues aren't -n(n+1) but rather $\sum_{0}^{\infty}a_nP_n$

Comment: sometimes my wording can be a little unclear so if that's the case here just ask me and I'll try and rephrase what I said :)

Comment: @can'tcauchy If $y = \sum_{n} c_n P_n(x)$ (for any choice of $c_n$'s), then can you show that $(1 - x^2) y'' - 2y' = - \sum_{n} n(n + 1) c_n P_n (x)$? Now we need to choose the $c_n$'s so that $(1 - x^2) y'' - 2y' = \sum_n \frac{1}{2^n} P_n(x)$...

Comment: ah okay so you multiply the rhs of the usual legendre equation by the function y, now we have on the rhs $-\sum_{0}^{\infty}n(n+1)c_nP_n(x)$ we need this to equal to $\sum_{0}^{\infty}\tfrac{1}{2^n}P_n(x)$ which implies that $c_n=-\tfrac{1}{2^n(n(n+1)}$ therefore our solution y must be $y=\sum-\tfrac{1}{2^n (n(n+1))}P_n(x)$

Comment: sorry we don't multiply it by y but rather we multiply by $c_n$ and sum